# Summarise numbers from objects based on country name (react, javascript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am dealing with an array of objects with usernames and 5 markets and number of people from each market reached by this person on social media.

I want to loop through all the objects and summarise how many people there are in each market across all users, back to me as the result.

Below is an example of one object. As you can see there is the market name for 1 market and value for market 1 after.

(I now that I have to revert the value into number and not a string, but please disregard that for now)

Any ideas of how to approach this seeing as there will be many markets coming up, meaning an if/else for each country is not possible since there can be a hundred country.

I think i need a function which will create a new array of all the numbers each time it encounters a new country and then take the sum of each array and return it.

[image]

Comment: Please post your code as text instead of a pic, and can you show us you're expected result?

Comment: Are objects in array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in other answer, [array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is the best way to handle cases like this.

```js
const obj1 = {
  'market-1-name': 'Russia',
  'market-1-value': '45532',
  'market-2-name': 'Finland',
  'market-2-value': '455321',
  'market-3-name': 'Germany',
  'market-3-value': '4553',
  'market-4-name': 'Austria',
  'market-4-value': '455232',
  username: 'someuser'
};

const obj2 = {
  'market-1-name': 'Russia',
  'market-1-value': '45532,321',
  'market-2-name': 'Finland',
  'market-2-value': '455321,334',
  'market-3-name': 'Germany',
  'market-3-value': '4553',
  'market-4-name': 'Austria',
  'market-4-value': '455232',
  username: 'blabla'
};

const objects = [obj1, obj2];
const nameRegex = /market-(\d+)-name/gm;
const valueRegex = /market-(\d+)-value/gm;

const sum = objects.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(cur).filter(key => key !== 'username');
  const names = keys.filter(key => key.match(nameRegex));
  const values = keys.filter(key => key.match(valueRegex));
  const mapping = {};

  names.forEach(name => {
    const num = name.replace(nameRegex, '$1');
    const country = cur[name];

    mapping[num] = country;
  });

  values.forEach(val => {
    const num = val.replace(valueRegex, '$1');
    const country = mapping[num];
    const value = parseFloat(cur[val]);

    if (!acc[country]) acc[country] = value;
    else acc[country] += value;
  });

  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this is just what I need!

Answer (score 1):

Could be done like this:

```js
const users = [
  { 
    'market-1-value' : 10,
    'market-2-value' : 20,
    'market-3-value' : 30,
    'market-4-value' : 40,
    'market-5-value' : 50,
  },
  { 
    'market-1-value' : 10,
    'market-2-value' : 20,
    'market-3-value' : 30,
    'market-4-value' : 40,
    'market-5-value' : 50,
  },
  { 
    'market-1-value' : 10,
    'market-2-value' : 20,
    'market-3-value' : 30,
    'market-4-value' : 40,
    'market-5-value' : 50,
  },
]

const initialVal =  { 
    'market-1-value' : 0,
    'market-2-value' : 0,
    'market-3-value' : 0,
    'market-4-value' : 0,
    'market-5-value' : 0,
  };
const totalInMarkets = users.reduce((a,b)=>{
    Object.keys(b).forEach(key=>a[key] += b[key] )
    return a
},initialVal)

console.log(totalInMarkets)
```